# Получить курс валют и вывод на своём сайте

Tags: php, javascript

Есть сайт http://www.moex.com/. Нужно вывести курс валютного рынка на своём сайте.
Какими средствами это можно сделать? Документации на их сайте к сожалению не нашел.
И возможно ли каждый промежуток времени этот курс обновлять без перезагрузки страницы? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

используйте php скрипт с curl-ом для парсинга нужной страницы, разбирайте результат с помощью того же simple dom html parser php и формируйте json.
Обращайтесь к этому серверному скрипту с клиента по ajax и будет вам счастье

Comment: Там этот график через JS формируется, поэтому в данном случае curl не сработает.

Comment: ну дак "через JS формируется" - откуда-то ведь JS их берет данные? а он берет с помощью ajax, обращаясь, к своим серверным скриптам. Нужно определить, например, с помощью консоли пути, параметры и все тем же прекрасно curl-ом забирать даннные